# Pandas sum multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have multiple dataframes each with a multi-level-index and a value column. I want to add up all the dataframes on the value columns.

`df1 + df2`

Not all the indexes are complete in each dataframe, hence I am getting `nan` on a row which is not present in all the dataframes.

How can I overcome this and treat rows which are not present in any dataframe as having a value of 0?

Eg. I want to get

```
   val
a    2
b    4
c    3
d    3
```

from `pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3}}) + pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'd':3}})` instead of

```
   val
a    2
b    4
c  NaN
d  NaN
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

use the `add` method with `fill_value=0` parameter.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'd':3}})

df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)

   val
a  2.0
b  4.0
c  3.0
d  3.0
```

---

#### MultiIndex example

```
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'A'), ('a', 'B'), ('b', 'A'), ('b', 'D')])
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'A'), ('a', 'C'), ('b', 'A'), ('b', 'C')])

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 1), idx1, ['val'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 1), idx2, ['val'])

df1

          val
a A -2.129724
  B -1.268466
b A -1.970500
  D -2.259055

df2

          val
a A -0.349286
  C -0.026955
b A  0.316236
  C  0.348782

df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)

          val
a A -2.479011
  B -1.268466
  C -0.026955
b A -1.654264
  C  0.348782
  D -2.259055
```

---

#### More than 2 dataframes

```
from functools import reduce

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'd':3}})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'e': 1, 'c':2, 'd':3}})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'f': 1, 'a':2, 'd':3}})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'g': 1, 'f':2, 'd':3}})

reduce(lambda a, b: a.add(b, fill_value=0), [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5])

    val
a   4.0
b   4.0
c   5.0
d  12.0
e   1.0
f   3.0
g   1.0
```

Comment: very neat answer! will it also work with a multiindex DFs?

Comment: If I have 3 dataframe, how to use **add** in a very simple way?

Comment: The answer I'd give would be different than this.  I suggest you ask another question.  That way everyone gets the benefit of seeing it.

Comment: @ZedFang I'll be waiting with an answer for when you ask this follow up question.

Comment: @piRSquared I think it would have helped everyone the most, if you just wrote your answer here, instead of adding two comments about how you would answer if there just was another question.
So, did you answer somewhere?

Comment: @schnaidar fair enough.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Mind that this will only work when the column names are the same in both dataframes. Else, it will concatenate the two dfs to.