# Sum a list of Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to sum multiple pandas DataFrames using syntax similar to `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4])`. I understand from documentation that I can do `df1.sum(df2, fill_value=0)`, but I have a long list of DataFrames I need to sum and was wondering if I could do it without writing a loop.

Somewhat related question/answer: [Pandas sum multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472276/pandas-sum-multiple-dataframes) (Stack Overflow)

Example of what the result should look like:

```
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'A'), ('a', 'B'), ('b', 'A'), ('b', 'D')])
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'A'), ('a', 'C'), ('b', 'A'), ('b', 'C')])
idx3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'A'), ('a', 'D'), ('b', 'A'), ('b', 'C')])

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 1), idx1, ['val'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 1), idx2, ['val'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 1), idx3, ['val'])
```

**df1**

[image]

**df2**

[image]

**df3**

[image]

**The result should look like:**

[image]

Comment: Are you just looking for an aggregated df with every element summed where the columns and index labels match? Or you want the sum for each column as a total? Please post the desired result

Comment: My apologies for the lack of clarity. Added screenshots to be more clear. @EdChum

Comment: @Jezrael's answer does what you want, I'm deleting mine now

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `reduce` with [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
np.random.seed(12)

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))
b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(5,2)), columns=list('ab'))
c = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(5,2)), columns=list('ac'))
print(a)
   a  b  c
0  2  1  1
1  2  0  0
2  2  1  0
3  1  1  1
4  2  2  2

print(b)
   a  b
0  0  1
1  0  0
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  0  1

print(c)
   a  c
0  2  0
1  2  2
2  2  0
3  0  2
4  1  1
```

---

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [a,b, c]
d = reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), dfs)
print (d)
   a    b    c
0  4  2.0  1.0
1  4  0.0  2.0
2  5  3.0  0.0
3  2  3.0  3.0
4  3  3.0  3.0
```

Comment: @EdChum - Thank you. By the way, you was big teacher for me some time ago, so thank you very much for you all answers ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit fussier with answering questions on SO nowadays, don't have so much time but interesting questions still pique my interest