# Pandas: cell-wise fillna(method = 'pad') of a list of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Basically, I'm trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45983359/189035) but for a `fillna` instead of a sum.

I have a list of df's, each with same colunms/indexes, ordered over time:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)

df_list = []
for index in range(3):
    a  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))
    mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=a.shape)
    df_list.append(a.mask(mask))
```

now, I want to do a replace the `numpy.nan` cells of the ith
`DataFrame` in `df_list` by the value of the same cell in the `i-1 th` 
`DataFrame` in `df_list`.

so if the first `DataFrame` is:

```
     a    b    c
 0  NaN  1.0  0.0
 1  1.0  1.0  NaN
 2  0.0  NaN  0.0
 3  NaN  0.0  2.0
 4  NaN  2.0  2.0
```

and the 2nd is:

```
     a    b    c
 0  0.0  NaN  NaN
 1  NaN  NaN  NaN
 2  0.0  1.0  NaN
 3  NaN  NaN  2.0
 4  0.0  NaN  2.0
```

Then the output `output_list` should be a list of the same length as `df_list` and having also DataFrames as elements.

The first entry of `output_list` is the same as the first entry of `df_list`.
The second entry of `output_list` is:

```
     a    b    c
 0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 1  1.0  1.0  NaN
 2  0.0  1.0  0.0
 3  NaN  0.0  2.0
 4  0.0  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `update` functionality is very good for this, see the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html
It is a method that specifically allows you to update a DataFrame, in your case only the NaN-elements of it.

In particular, you could use it like this:

```
new_df_list = df_list[:1]
for df_new, df_old  in zip(df_list[1:], df_list[:-1]):
    df_new.update(df_old, overwrite=False)
    new_df_list.append(df_new)
```

Which will give you the desired output

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you print the .head() and .info(), I'm sure we can figure it out

Comment: added to the question!