# Elegant way to add rows of multiple dataframes by common index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of ~5,000 dataframes, each with ~20 columns and ~15,000 rows. All dataframes share the same column names, and I would like to elegantly sum all data in all dataframes for the same value in "time". An example is shown below for 2 dataframes. The key here is getting this done as efficiently as possible.

df1 =

```
time    data1   data2
0       100     100
1       100     100
2       100     100
```

df2 =

```
time    data1   data2
1       100     100
2       100     100
3       100     100
```

output =

```
time    data1   data2
0       100     100
1       200     200
2       200     200
3       100     100
```

Comment: Why do you have so many different data frames with the same construction?  A better solution would be to combine all the data into 1 data frame and if there is some difference between the data frames, add a single column to denote the difference.

Comment: @JeffH The multiple dataframes have similar construction but their data vary widely. Without boring you with too much detail, each dataframe represents a distinct point in space. I am looping through each point - and generating a dataframe - and would like to combine all dataframes into a global picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html), which will add matching indices. In this case, you want to match on time, so you can set it as the index.

```
df1.set_index('time').add(df2.set_index('time'), fill_value=0)

      data1  data2
time              
0     100.0  100.0
1     200.0  200.0
2     200.0  200.0
3     100.0  100.0
```

Fill value is set to `0` so that if there is a value in one dataframe but not the other, the missing one is taken to be 0.

Comment: This works well with small amounts of dataframes. For a list of 5000 dataframes, for example, I don't believe using a for loop and your method would be most efficient. I've discovered the following suggestion as an alternative. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983321/sum-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes