# How can I add DataFrames like Matrices Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a LONG list of dataframes (with many columns ...) like so:

```
DF1
    nameOne     total_one       total_two       nameTwo    nameThree    ...
0       nn1             2               3           nn4          nn7
1       nn2             2               3           nn5          nn8
2       nn3             2               3           nn6          nn9

DF2
    nameOne     total_one       total_two      nameTwo    nameThree.    ....
0       nn1             4               6          nn4          nn7
1       nn2             4               6          nn5          nn8
2       nn3             4               6          nn6          nn9
```

What I want the result to look like:

```
RESULT_DF
    nameOne     total_one       total_two   nameTwo    nameThree.   ....
0       nn1             6               9       nn4          nn7
1       nn2             6               9       nn5          nn8
2       nn3             6               9       nn6          nn9
```

In other words, I just want to add the number columns.

I tried doing this: `DF1.add(DF2, fill_value=0)`

But I get this error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'**

For brevity, here I only showed one Str column. But I have many more STR columns, and many more int/float columns.

Explanation: Please note this is not the same as [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983321/sum-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes) question because I mentioned that I have multiple string fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas sum multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472276/pandas-sum-multiple-dataframes)

Comment: That's what I tried above. It does not handle the case where you have strings since it does not know how to add them.

Comment: That's precisely what the second option does, you need to set `nameOne` as the index

Comment: I am not following.

Comment: `cols = ['total_one', 'total_two']; df = df1.copy(); df[cols] = df1[cols] + df2[cols]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `select_dtypes` and `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1.select_dtypes(include='number').add(df2.select_dtypes(include='number')),
           df1.select_dtypes(exclude='number'), 
           df2.select_dtypes(exclude='number')], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   total_one  total_two nameOne nameOne
0          6          9     nn1     nn1
1          6          9     nn2     nn2
2          6          9     nn3     nn3
```

---

#### Adding list of dataframes

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df4 = df2.copy()

lofdfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

from functools import reduce
df_add = reduce(lambda x,y: x.select_dtypes(include='number').add(y.select_dtypes('number')), lofdfs)
pd.concat([i.select_dtypes(exclude='number') for i in lofdfs]+[df_add], axis=1, keys=['df1','df2','df3','df4','df_add'])
```

Output:

```
      df1     df2     df3     df4    df_add          
  nameOne nameOne nameOne nameOne total_one total_two
0     nn1     nn1     nn1     nn1        12        18
1     nn2     nn2     nn2     nn2        12        18
2     nn3     nn3     nn3     nn3        12        18
```

Moving totals to the front:

```
df_add = reduce(lambda x,y: x.select_dtypes(include='number').add(y.select_dtypes('number')), lofdfs)
print(pd.concat([df_add]+[i.select_dtypes(exclude='number') for i in lofdfs], axis=1, keys=['df1','df2','df3','df4','df_add']))
```

Output:

```
        df1               df2     df3     df4  df_add
  total_one total_two nameOne nameOne nameOne nameOne
0        12        18     nn1     nn1     nn1     nn1
1        12        18     nn2     nn2     nn2     nn2
2        12        18     nn3     nn3     nn3     nn3
```

Comment: Scott - how would i do this for a list of dataframes?

Comment: @DonCode Not sure if this is what you needed, but see update.

Comment: Ålmost -- i am mostly interested in the totals - not so much on the names. I would like to have them in the end result but not necessary.

Comment: @DonCode Just move the df_add in the pd.concat first.

Comment: Can we do it somehow without specifying the keys=['df1','df2','df3','df4','df_add'] ? 

My list has many elements so this would not work.

Comment: Also, for the addition - some values I want to add are with % some are just integers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way
use `df.filter` to filter out `DF2`'s numeric columns. Add them to `DF1`. What results is aggregated results of numeric columns and NaNs for the str. Chain `combine_first` and this updates the NaNS

**Option1; 2 dataframes**

If have only two datframes

```
RESULT_DF=(DF2.filter(like='total').add(DF1)).combine_first(DF1)
RESULT_DF

   nameOne nameThree nameTwo  total_one  total_two
0     nn1       nn7     nn4          6          9
1     nn2       nn8     nn5          6          9
2     nn3       nn9     nn6          6          9
```

**Option2 list of datframes**

If you have lists; select non numeric dtypes and join to summation after using reduce in from functools

```
DF3 = DF2.copy()
DF4 = DF1.copy()
LST=[DF1,DF2,DF3]

from functools import reduce
df = DF1.select_dtypes(exclude='int64').join(reduce(lambda x, y:\
(x.filter(like='total')).add(y.filter(like='total'), fill_value=0), LST))
print(df)



  nameOne nameTwo nameThree  total_one  total_two
0     nn1     nn4       nn7         10         15
1     nn2     nn5       nn8         10         15
2     nn3     nn6       nn9         10         15
```

Comment: Does this help?